# export NODE_ENV=production doesn't change process.env.NODE_ENV in gulpfile.js

Tags: node.js, macos, gulp, environment-variables

I'm trying to set the environment variable $NODE_ENV to "production" with

```
export NODE_ENV=production
```

but when I try to run my gulp task, it says the variable is undefined:

```
if((process.env.NODE_ENV).trim().toLowerCase() !== 'production') {
                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mmarinescu/Projects/gulpTutorial/gulpfile.js:15:26)
at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
at require (module.js:385:17)
at Liftoff.handleArguments (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:116:3)
at Liftoff.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/liftoff/index.js:192:16)
at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/liftoff/node_modules/flagged-respawn/index.js:17:3)
```

If I `echo $NODE_ENV`, however, it shows the production keyword.

My gulp setup in this example is as it follows:

```
var devBuild = ((process.env.NODE_ENV).trim().toLowerCase() !== 'production')
```

If I'm using the full initialisation of devBuild, it is always true, as it doesn't consider the $NODE_ENV change in my terminal

```
var devBuild = ((process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development').trim().toLowerCase() !== 'production')
```

Does anyone know why doesn't the variable update in my gulpfile and how can I fix this?

Running on a MAC OSX EL Capitan

Thanks in advance!

LATER EDIT:

I think the error appears because I'm using sudo gulp html;

The reason I'm using sudo is because when I'm using gulp html, I get this error:

```
gulptutorial 1.0.0, production build
[00:44:21] Using gulpfile ~/Projects/gulpTutorial/gulpfile.js
[00:44:21] Starting 'html'...
[00:44:22] 'html' errored after 101 ms
[00:44:22] Error: EACCES: permission denied, open      '/Users/mmarinescu/Projects/gulpTutorial/build/index.html'
at Error (native)
```

gulp task is:

```
gulp.task('html', function() {
var page = gulp.src(html.in).pipe(preprocess({ context: html.context }));//we add the preprocessed html to a var
if(!devBuild) { //global variable defined on step 7
    page = page.pipe(htmlclean());//minifying the html only if we're in the production mode

    console.log(devBuild)
}
return page.pipe(gulp.dest(html.out))
})
```

where

```
html = {
    in: source + '*.html',
    out: dest,
    context: {
        devBuild: devBuild
    }
};
```

and

```
var source = 'source/',
dest = 'build/';
```

If I use gulp html, the variable changes to production, but I get the error, if I'm using sudo gulp html the task goes through, but the variable doesn't change...

```
gulpTutorial mmarinescu$ export   NODE_ENV=production
gulpTutorial mmarinescu$  gulp html
gulptutorial 1.0.0, production build
[00:58:12] Using gulpfile ~/Projects/gulpTutorial/gulpfile.js
[00:58:12] Starting 'html'...
[00:58:12] 'html' errored after 87 ms
[00:58:12] Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/mmarinescu/Projects/gulpTutorial/build/index.html'
at Error (native)
```

vs

```
gulpTutorial mmarinescu$ sudo gulp html
gulptutorial 1.0.0, development build
[01:02:10] Using gulpfile ~/Projects/gulpTutorial/gulpfile.js
[01:02:10] Starting 'html'...
[01:02:10] Finished 'html' after 67 ms
```

NOTE, the NODE_ENV variable is production in both cases...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using sudo you are running the process as a different user (root). That is why environment variables are undefined. Try setting the right permissions on your files and you should be able to run without sudo

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is no problem with this code `if((process.env.NODE_ENV).trim().toLowerCase() !== 'production') {` but better you discard brackets `if(process.env.NODE_ENV.trim().toLowerCase() !== 'production') {`

for the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined` it is because environment NODE_ENV there is no value.

try to check again on NODE_ENV.

also try check with `$ NODE_ENV=production gulp [tasks]`

Comment: nope...this doesn't solve it. updated my issue again

Answer (score 1):

After more investigation and discussion with SLow Loris, I found different solutions:

1. Change the file permissions of the error file:

   Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/mmarinescu/Projects/gulpTutorial/build/index.html'

by writing:

```
chmod 755 /Users/mmarinescu/Projects/gulpTutorial/build/index.html
```

The downside to this is that I need to set the permission with chmod 755, I need to set the permission again each time I'm running 'gulp html'

2. use `sudo su` in the project folder, then `export NODE_ENV=production` or `export NODE_ENV=development` and run `gulp html` - this works okay without running again the file permissions command
3. delete the index.html file, as it will be re-written again by the gulp command: the index.html is created from the build folder to the production one. you can do this either by deleting it manually or by setting up a gulp task, `gulp clean`; you set up this task after installing the npm del package, `sudo npm install del --save-dev`, then in gulpfile.js

   delModule = require('del');
   gulp.task('clean', function () {
   delModule([dest + '*']); //passing into del an array of strings, in this case, just the build folder with all it's files
   })

Comment: don't know why, but my mac had only read permissions on my folder, so I followed the steps in this tutorial to add read/write permissions: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18894?locale=en_US

Comment: To avoid having to deal with file permissions in the future you can slightly modify your setup. I've found a really good tutorial on the subject: [How to use npm global without sudo on OSX](http://www.johnpapa.net/how-to-use-npm-global-without-sudo-on-osx/)

However, this means you'll have to reinstall your global packages, but you'll never have to do `sudo npm install --global ***` again.

Comment: thanks for the help! turns out that the main issue was from the files I've been using, which had only read permissions on them... managed to set the permissions on these files to read & write and now I can use the NODE_ENV as it should, without the need to use sudo or sudo su, etc.

Answer (score 0):

use export NODE_ENV = "production". if your production variable is not initialized as a string, trim doesn't work on it.

Comment: this doesn't solve it, updated my issue with extra info